# React Native crash when register exist user by RxJS ajax

Tags: ajax, react-native, rxjs, strapi

I am register new strapi user by RxJS ajax. When user already exist, I expect the 'user already exist' return but It crash my app.

```
Unhandled JS Exception: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

How to handle error with RxJS ajax?

```
import { ajax } from "rxjs/ajax";
import { map, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

const testAjax = () => {
  const test$ = ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:1337/auth/local/register",
    method: "POST",
    body: {
      username: "email3@test.com",
      email: "email3@test.com",
      password: "password"
    }
  })
    .pipe(
      map(userResponse => userResponse),
      catchError(error => console.log("Error: ", error))
    )
    .subscribe(({ response }) => {
      console.log("res: ", response);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you! The catchError don't return stream data, so I have to use 'of' -> of(error). Problem solved

Comment: The correct one is: catchError(error => of(error)) . Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

did you try console userResponse , `map(userResponse => console.log('users: ', userResponse))`, may be there was the reason for the crash